# How can I control the time of the light of the display

Tags: android

I want to keep the the display on whilst the application is running, i.e. I don't want the device to get locked whilst the application is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is WakeLock. You should look to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

You need this permission: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

Then you can just do something like this:

> PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>   mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "My Tag");
>   mWakeLock.acquire();

To remove the WakeLock just call:

> mWakeLock.release();

Answer (score 0):

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

Also need to add android.permission.WAKE_LOCK to manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using wake-locks, you can also use:

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`